# Floats appearing in wrong places

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx

In Lyx I'm using float figures.

I have to put three pictures one after the other, so three different float figures.

When I output a pdf, the floats all appear at the top of three different pages.

Why is this happening?

Comment: As you already mention, `figure`s are considered "floats", so they move around in your document. If you don't want them to float, then you need consider other choices. How big are these figures? If you don't want them at the location they're appearing now, what is the desired layout?

Comment: If you don't need them as floats, just do Insert > Graphics in LyX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can choose the placement of float through

Document -> Setting ... Float Placement

[image]

Comment: Potentially a stupid question but why isn't "here definitely" the default option? In fact, why would anyone want their images/charts/etc to be positioned anywhere other that where they put the image?

Comment: @J.J The purpose of floating figures and tables is to avoid the situation where you end up with a page with a lot of whitespace, because the figure/table just didn't fit in the current page. So you allow floating which will fill the page with text, and use cross-references to refer to a figure. Granted, this isn't useful in *all* types of documents, and a lot of people do find it weird at first.